# Success PresignedPost uploads on HTML but failed in Postman

Tags: amazon-s3, postman, multipartform-data

So I just tried PresignedPost from AWS Documentation and have this code

```
<html>
  <head>
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    
  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Key to upload: 
    <input type="input"  name="key" value="user/user1/${filename}" /><br />
    Content-Type: 
    <input type="input"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20151229T000000Z" />

    Tags for File: 

    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value='<Base64-encoded policy string>' />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<signature-value>" />
    File: 
    <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
    <!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>
  
</html>
```

And my conditions I have set to

```
 Conditions: [
    ['content-length-range', 1, 10 * 1024 * 1024],
    ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', 'image/'],
  ],
```

When I send it from HTML file, the upload success with 204 Status Code. But when I try from Postman I have error with the message:

```
Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"]
```

Even I already included "Content-Type" field and still get Error. I wondering what the problem is.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It's the order of fields.
When `Content-Type` is set before `file` then the upload success, But when `Content-Type` set after `file` then the error show up.

I confirm this behavior in the HTML file too.